# Following Apple's app icon guidelines won't give corner radius to macOS app icon

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I'm new to macOS app development.

**Problem: Uploading square shape PNG image with no rounder corner doesn't make my macOS app have a rounded corner**

At [here](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/macos/icons-and-images/app-icon) Apple says to upload an app icon image with no rounded corner.

[image]
In the case of iOS or iPadOS, if I just upload a square shape icon with no corner radius, Xcode automatically added corner radiuses. But in the case of macOS, Xcode doesn't.

What should I do to fix this issue?

Xcode 12.5

macOS: 11.0.1 Beta

Native macOS app

Comment: If you want your macOS app to have rounded corners, add them to the image you upload.

Comment: @jnpdx But, in Apple Human Interface Guidelines, they said upload image with no rounded corners. Is it OK not to follow that rule?

Comment: are you sure that is in the macOS HIG? I think it is only in the iOS one.

Comment: yes, in this Apple macOS HIG App Icon Attributes section
  (https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/macos/icons-and-images/app-icon) it says 'Square with no rounded corners'

Comment: Hmm. Misprint? Look at the icons on that page — very few would work with automatically rounded corners like on iOS because the shape isn’t exact (like Final Cut or Preview). Also, Mac icons don’t *have to* have rounded corners.

Comment: @jnpdx Thanks for the info, I gotta try submitting my app again with the rounded corner app icon.

Comment: Hi Seungjun, did you find a solution to it? I have similar problem when uploading my app to ios app store. I am building a react-native app using expo. Here is the question I have posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67514693/ios-app-icon-keeping-square-and-not-rounded-corners

Comment: @ArvindK. yesterday, I submitted a macOS app with a rounded corner app icon image unlike their HIG but got approved.!. Addressing this I sent an email to Apple Developer Support, will update it when I got a reply back

Comment: Thank you Seungjun! Do you mean you submitted one with transparency? 
I tried to arrange a support call, got call twice and then got disconnected. Expecting today as well. Please keep posted.

Comment: Btw, I create an icon with rounded corners and tried to build via expo build:ios and have this error `Your app icon can't have transparency if you wish to upload your app Apple's App Store. Read more here: https://expo.fyi/remove-alpha-channel`

Comment: No problem @ArvindK.
btw My app icon image doesn’t include any transparency.
Under my guess, it seems you give a rounded corner to the app icon and made the remaining space of the square to be transparent. 

 The icon image I used was like the following: starting with a square shape and trimmed each corner making it to be rounded corner.

Comment: @Seungjun Trimmed? What did you fill in the trimmed area? White color? Since it did not accept transparency I am uploading new icon, all square again which white background around so it does not look like touching edges.https://www.dropbox.com/s/mz32h6p987v4nkd/icon.png?dl=0

Comment: @ArvindK. sorry for my late response, (1)I was trying to post an answer back if I got hear back from the Apple Developer support team, as now the reply I got is 'I appreciate your input on the matter~~' (2) to be more specifically, the better expression would be NONE for remaining space, like my current icon which got approved: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zFC-Bp3phYcWmyahNOp-L2etAulDHL_L/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Seungjun - It's great that it got approved with transparency. I am trying to build via expo and they do not allow transparency since they seem to strictly follow Apple's HIG I believe. I am not sure how to upload a transparent icon manually for approval. Trying to figure out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The latest guidelines (found [here](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/foundations/app-icons)) specify "Square with rounded corners" for a Mac icon.

Tip: if you want your icons to use the same dimensions and shadows as the standard Mac apps, you can download official templates from [Apple Design Resources](https://developer.apple.com/design/resources/).