# iOS App Icon keeping square and not rounded corners

Tags: ios, react-native, icons, expo, rounded-corners

I am building a react native iOS app using expo. Here is the top part of App.json

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "CORT",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
```

As per the Apple documentation, i.e.

https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/app-icon/

*Keep icon corners square. The system applies a mask that rounds icon corners automatically.*

I am keeping square icon. However when I build and publish icon to App store it shows square icon within a rounded cornered gray box everywhere. See https://www.dropbox.com/s/iee0we9ktr0tjvg/CortSqureLogoAtAppStoreReview.jpg?dl=0

Also the the App Store Installation page https://www.dropbox.com/s/yoeb2q7cy4rjggh/Skype_Picture_2021_05_13T05_59_20_238Z.jpeg?dl=0

It does not let the app build if I try a manual rounded cornered square icon. the `expo build:ios` fails with:

`Your app icon can't have transparency if you wish to upload your app Apple's App Store. Read more here: https://expo.fyi/remove-alpha-channel`

I am not sure what wrong I am doing. An help is appreciated!

Comment: I suggest using this page [https://appiconmaker.co/](https://appiconmaker.co/) for making icons

Comment: how and why does that matter? Btw, expo required just one 1024x1024 png icon and I have that very well created and supplied.

Comment: @ArvindK. Was this fixed? If so, how? I recently uploaded a Safari App Extension on the Mac App Store but the icon still has a square background.

Comment: @onetrueshady - Yes it was fixed. I had to contact Apple Support and let them know about the issue and it was fixed automatically in next build. Seems like a bug in at their end.